# esxi 5.5 unable to detect previous hard disk

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, hard-drive, datastore

I have a 129GB SSD on HP Proliant DL380 G7 with ESXi 5.5 installed from a pen drive. The hard drive contains 2 virtual machines that contain a lot of work in them. I had to remove the drive as I am planning to set up a RAID 5 setup. After removing the drive I realized that I might have to copy the vm machines to a different drive and then set up the RAID. But I am unable to mount the drive and I cannot find it in the Vsphere Client.

I have an Ubuntu laptop that has an external SATA port and I tried to connect this hard drive to copy the files, and Ubuntu cannot identify my file system as it is VMFS.

Is there a way that I can copy those virtual machine files into a different drive using this Ubuntu laptop and then upload it back once the RAID setup is completed?

Answer (score 0):

Followed the instructions from the following link.

http://woshub.com/how-to-access-vmfs-datastore-from-linux-windows/

I was able to copy all the contents of the hard drive into my Ubuntu machine and I just copied it back to the server when the RAID set up is complete.